# Good Java Web Page Rendering Libraries

Tags: java, html, html-parsing, rendering

I need a good page rendering library so that I can extract all links(including anchor text, the underlying hyperlink, absolute position of the link on the page) from a web page.

I have been using the CSSBox library, however, the href attribute is missing from the rendered box model. In other words, I can only obtain anchor text and position of the link using CSSBox alone. I have to take advantage of the anchor text and another html parsing library(e.g.,Jsoup) to get the href attribute(i.e., the de facto URL).

Is there any library that can better achieve my goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Recommendation

Consider using [Geb](http://www.gebish.org/):

> It brings together the power of `WebDriver`, the elegance of `jQuery`
>   content selection, the robustness of `Page Object` modelling and the
>   expressiveness of the `Groovy` language.
>
> It can be used for scripting, scraping and general automation — or
>   equally as a functional/web/acceptance testing solution via
>   integration with testing frameworks such as `Spock`, `JUnit` & `TestNG`.

### Requirements

As mentioned, this is only suitable if you are open to the use of [Groovy](http://groovy.codehaus.org/). However, since Groovy integrates so easily with Java, this typically isn't a problem.

Furthermore, this will require a browser. I'm not sure if this is a deal breaker for you.

### Usage

From the [docs](http://www.gebish.org/manual/current/navigator.html#size_and_location):

> You can obtain the size and location of content on the page. All units
>   are in pixels. The size is available via the height and width
>   properties, while the location is available as the x and y properties
>   which represent the distance from the top left of the page (or parent
>   frame) to the top left point of the content.

For example:

```
Browser.drive {
  // Load the page
  go "http://myapp.com"

  // $("a") returns all hyperlinks on the page, similar to jQuery
  $("a").each { a ->
     // Display the required link properties and attributes
     println """
        The link to '${a.@href}' with text '${a.text()}' is at location (${a.x}, ${a.y}),
        with a height of ${a.height}px and a width of ${a.width}px.
     """
  }
}
```

Comment: Does Jerry provide a function for retrieving the position of an html element?

Comment: @TerryLi in what sense? Within the parent? Yes, by using `index`.

Comment: The absolute position of an element on the page, i.e., x and y coordinates.

Comment: @TerryLi, no this is strictly for html parsing. I'm totally sorry as I misread your question. I didn`t see the absolute positioning requirement.

Comment: @TerryLi hopefully my updated answer is more useful to you. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: When I try to get the location, it gives a JavascriptNotEnabled error. How can I set it to be enabled?

Comment: @TerryLi Try adding `driver.webClient.javaScriptEnabled = true` before `go`.

Answer (score 1):

You may do this with [CSSBox](http://cssbox.sourceforge.net/) pretty easily. Each `ElementBox` instance has the `getElement()` that obtains the corresponding DOM Element. That means, having an element box `a` representing the rendered link, you may obtain the target url using `a.getElement().getAttribute("href")`. See also the related topic in the [CSSBox discussion forum](http://sourceforge.net/p/cssbox/discussion/752160/thread/6664381a/).

Comment: OMG...I didn't notice that...You are my life saver!Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

In case you need a parser, so you can see all links of a HTML page and do whatever you need to do, I recommend Jericho.

[Jericho HTML Parser](http://jericho.htmlparser.net/docs/index.html) is a java library allowing analysis and manipulation of parts of an HTML document, including server-side tags, while reproducing verbatim any unrecognised or invalid HTML. It also provides high-level HTML form manipulation functions.

It's easy and small and have decent performance

Comment: Can you render a web-page with Jericho? The OP wants to know the 'absolute position' of a certain element on a web page (though I doubt that this is renderer independent).

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't find any method in Jericho that retrieves the position of an html element for me.

Comment: No, I'm sorry. I'll edit my answer

Answer (score 0):

You may want to have a look at http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net. It's not a renderer but more a GUI-less browser. It even supports various JavaScript engines and ActiveX.

However I'm pretty sure you can't use it to track the position of any element since it doesn't actually render a webpage.

Answer (score 0):

JavaFX's WebEngine might work for you: http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/web/WebEngine.html

I won't call it easy to use or lightweight, but have a look.